# bind draggable marker with polyline google map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-markers, google-polyline, google-maps-react

Hi I have connection between marker with polyline like this Image . I am attaching a sample here.
[image: polyline with markers]

I have added polyline with marker.i'am drawing polyline and marker on 'click' event. basicaly markers are with numbered path. what i actualy want - i'am able to edit polylines and markers separately but i want to bind marker with polyline. when i dragging marker poyline should also drag with marker. you can se my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/thisstate-is-not-defined-in-initmap-jxytg?file=/src/MapComponent.jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue using marker 'drag' event. on drag event i'am redrawing the Polyline with new path. like that way.

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "drag", (mark) => {
      let lat = mark.latLng.lat().toString();
      let lng = mark.latLng.lng().toString();
      this.setState((state) => ({
        ...state,
        lattitude: lat,
        longitude: lng,
      }));
      let newPath = polyPath;
      newPath[marker.index-1] = mark.latLng;
      poly.setMap(null);
      poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        strokeColor: "orange",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 5,
        path: newPath,
        geodesic:false,
      });
      poly.setMap(map);
  });
```